# view document in asp.net from local host using google document viewer

Tags: asp.net, google-document-viewer

I am using google docs to view document in asp.net using local host. But it gives error no preview available. Below code is using to display document

```
 <a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://localhost:59091/App_Data/7.jpg&embedded=true" target="_blank">Preview</a>
```

How to show documents from local host?